# Q: Constructing Matrix for a Tight Frame

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Consider a frame $\Phi = \{\varphi_1, ..., \varphi_m\}$ for $\Bbb C ^n$ consisting of $m \geq n$ vectors.  Denote the frame bounds by $A \leq B$, the Bessel map and its associated $m \times n$ matrix both by $T$, and the frame operator and its associated $n \times n$ positive definite matrix by $\Bbb T$.

Let $C$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix and define $\Psi = \{C\varphi_1, ..., C\varphi_m\}$.  Show $\Psi$ is a frame and determine a matrix $C$ so that $\Psi$ is a tight frame with bound one.

---

My thoughts:

I am fairly new to this kind of material and I think understanding the setup is the biggest hurdle for me at the moment.  I'm not sure if I'm going about this properly but I'm thinking that since $C$ is invertible, it maps one-to-one.  Therefore, $\Psi$ is just a linear combination of $\Phi$ and covers the same span.

The conditions for a frame are:
\begin{equation}
A||x||^2 \leq \sum_{k \in K} |<x, \varphi_k>|^2 \leq B||x||^2 
\end{equation}

$\forall x \in \mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $0 < A \leq B < \infty$

I know a tight frame is when the lower and upper bounds (A and B) are are equal to each other, but I am not sure how to go about finding a matrix so that requirement is fulfilled.

Comment: If you denote $\Phi$ the $n\times m$ matrix whose columns are $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_m$, the frame condition is simply that $\Phi\Phi^*$ be invertible. What is $\Psi\Psi^*$ if $\psi_j=C\phi_j$?

Comment: Would it be $C\phi C^*\phi^*$ and since C is invertible and we know $\phi\phi^*$ is invertible then $\Psi\Psi^*$ is invertible, thus fulfilling the frame condition?

Comment: No, it is $C\Phi(C\Phi)^*=C\Phi\Phi^*C^*$. You also have a typo in your frame condition: it should be $\|x\|^2$ and not $\|x^2\|$. You can also verify this directly on the double inequality for the $\psi_j=C\phi_j$.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing that out.  In regards to the "tightness" of the frame, I'm guessing we want $\Psi\Psi^* = C\Phi\Phi^*C^*$ to equal the identity matrix?

Comment: That's what they call a Parseval frame. A tight frame is just when you get a scalar matrix.

Comment: Ok, I have been going through Ole Christensen's book and see that is true.  However, seeing how I need a tight frame with bound 1, the Parseval frame is what I am indeed striving for, correct?  Also, we know that the frame operator $\mathcal{T} = T^*T$ and if this equals some constant times the identity matrix, then it is tight with bounds of that constant.  Is it appropriate to look for $CT^*T = \mathcal{I}$?


By the way, I greatly appreciate the help and the back and forth.

Comment: I see, I had not seen the bound one. Yes, you want $C$ such that $\Psi$ be a Parseval frame, that is $\Psi\Psi^*=I_n$, i.e. $C\Phi\Phi^*C^*=I_n$, i.e. $\Phi\Phi^*=C^{-1}(C^{-1})^*$. You have a lot of choices. The easiest is probably to use the square root of $\Phi\Phi^*$.